# ¿Cómo salgo de mi programa de otra forma?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Realice un programa sencillo, 100% funcional, pero tengo un duda muy grande: tuve que poner un `while` True porque de otra forma solo se ejecutaba una vez.

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que mi programa termine? Cuando pregunta que quiero hacer y pongo salir, deja de mostrar cosas, pero no me deja salir.

Estuve viendo de varias formas: si movía el último `break` ya hacia otras cosas, como que se salía cuando ejecutaba cada `while` una vez y ya no me dejaba volver a agregar, etc.

Mi solución fue poner al final otro `if` que confirmara que quiero salir y ahí si ya se detiene, pero quiero saber de que otra forma o cual es la adecuada para realizar ese tipo de tareas

```
claves = {}
respuesta = "salir"
respuesta = input("¿Que desea hacer, añadir o pagar una factura o salir?: ")

while True:
    while respuesta == "añadir":
        llave = input("Ingrese el numero de la factura deseada: ")
        valor = int(input("Ingrese su monto: "))
        claves[llave] = valor
        suma = 0
        for n in claves:
            suma += claves[n]
        for y in claves:
            print(y, ":", claves[y])
        print(f"\nEl valor total de las facturas es: {suma}")
        respuesta = input("\n¿Que desea hacer, añadir o pagar una factura o salir?: ")

    while respuesta == "pagar":
        llave = input("Ingrese el numero de la factura deseada: ")
        claves.pop(llave)
        resta = 0
        for m in claves:
            resta -= claves[m]
        for z in claves:
            print(z, ":", claves[z])
        print(f"\nEl valor total de las facturas es: {resta * -1}")
        respuesta = input("\n¿Que desea hacer, añadir o pagar una factura o salir?: ")

    while respuesta == "salir":
        break
    if respuesta == "salir":
        break
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este tipo de aplicaciones tiene una estructura estándar: un ciclo infinito dentro del cual pides una opciones y ejecutas la acción asociada. O sea, una serie de `if-else` dentro de un `while True`.

```
while True:
   opcion = input("Opcion:")
   if opcion == 1:
       ejecutar_1()
   elif opcion == 2:
       ejecutar_2()
   ...
   else:
       ejecutar_n()
```

¿Por qué se queda pegado tu código? Por esto:

```
while respuesta == "salir":
        break
```

Si `respuesta` es salir, ejecuta un `break` que lo saca de este `while`, pero no del `while True` global. Por eso necesitas agregarle un `if` a continuación.
Aplicado a tu caso en particular, queda así:

```
claves = {}

while True:
    respuesta = input("¿Que desea hacer, añadir o pagar una factura o salir?: ")

    if  respuesta == "añadir":
        llave = input("Ingrese el numero de la factura deseada: ")
        valor = int(input("Ingrese su monto: "))
        claves[llave] = valor
        suma = 0
        for n in claves:
            suma += claves[n]
        for y in claves:
            print(y, ":", claves[y])
        print(f"\nEl valor total de las facturas es: {suma}")
        respuesta = input("\n¿Que desea hacer, añadir o pagar una factura o salir?: ")
    elif respuesta == "pagar":
        llave = input("Ingrese el numero de la factura deseada: ")
        claves.pop(llave)
        resta = 0
        for m in claves:
            resta -= claves[m]
        for z in claves:
            print(z, ":", claves[z])
        print(f"\nEl valor total de las facturas es: {resta * -1}")
        respuesta = input("\n¿Que desea hacer, añadir o pagar una factura o salir?: ")
    elif respuesta == "salir":
        break
```